# Xagent to act as proxy for serving up non SSL data in an SSL environment

Tags: ssl, proxy, xpages

Our intranet is required to use https:// at all times which is fine for data stored on our own servers but causes problems for data fetched from third party sites. For example we have a list of currency exchange rates that comes from a third party site. The third party site does not offer an https option. To avoid the content being blocked by IE (and now even Firefox since the latest release!) it seems like a good idea to get the third party data via a proxy. Our admins are not keen on setting up an Apache server to act as a proxy and have asked me to investigate "doing it through Xpages". I'm a complete Java newbie and I'm struggling to understand why my Xagent doesn't work.

Here's what I've done so far: Stephan Wissel has written an HTTPReader class in Java which I've managed to add to my nsf. I've written an Xagent which successfully calls the getURL method of this class and fetches the content of the remote URL as a string. The problem I'm having is reading the string so that I can write it back. I get an "Error while executing JavaScript action expression" error on the BufferedReader line. This is my Xagent code:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:importPackage(org.lotususers.tools);
importPackage(java.io);

var httpReader = org.lotususers.tools.HTTPReader();
var remoteURL = context.getUrlParameter("ru");
var remoteHTML:String = httpReader.getURL(remoteURL);

var bufferedReader:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remoteHTML));

var outputString = "";
while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
    outputString += bufferedReader.readLine();
};

var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = externalContext.getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

writer.write(outputString);
writer.endDocument();
}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

If I put a line to print `remoteHTML` to the console (ie. print(remoteHTML)) then I can see the HTML has been fetched successfully, so at least I know that part has worked.

I've spent hours reading documentation about BufferedReader and trying to figure out what I've done wrong. I've tried every variation I can find for the BufferedReader line but nothing works (`.openStream()` or `.getInputStream()`). For example:

`var bufferedReader:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remoteHTML.getInputStream()));`

I've tried fully qualifying the paths too but this made no difference:

`var bufferedReader:java.io.BufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(remoteHTML.getInputStream()));`

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what's wrong with that line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: check for a more detailed error message in your XPages log files. This error message will probably help you a lot. For easy access to the XPages log files use Log File Reader from OpenNTF: http://www.openntf.org/p/XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful suggestion. I've installed the Log File Reader and found more details about the error. It is **Cannot find java public constructor 'java.io.InputStreamReader(java.lang.String)'**. I'm still no wiser though! Every SSJS example I've found that uses BufferedReader also uses InputStreamReader and none of them do more than **importPackage(java.io)**. Do I need to import something else?

Comment: The constructors for java.io.InputStreamReader expects an inputStream. So search for reading an URL. This might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: To avoid hunting errors in SSJS, try to write all the logic in Java class. Then simply call required method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
    outputString += bufferedReader.readLine();
};
```

you would miss every second line to put in outputString and in addition it might happen after last line was read in while condition that `outputString += bufferedReader.readLine();` would throw an JavaScript error because there is no line anymore.

Instead use this code:

```
var line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while(line != null){
    outputString += line;
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
};
```

**EDIT:**

The following XAgent should do what you are looking for. `httpReader.getURL(remoteURL)` delivers you already complete HTML so you can use it right away for writer and don't have to deal with stream.

```js
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try { 
    var httpReader = org.lotususers.tools.HTTPReader();
    var remoteURL = context.getUrlParameter("ru");
    var remoteHTML = httpReader.getURL(remoteURL);
    var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
    var response = externalContext.getResponse(); 
    var writer = response.getWriter(); 
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
    writer.write(remoteHTML); 
    facesContext.responseComplete(); 
} catch (e) { 
    _dump(e); 
}}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

The XAgent returns the page content of a target URL which is defined by parameter "ru". This is an example URL for calling XAgent:

```
https://Server/Test.nsf/XAgent.xsp?ru=http://www.web.de
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sure you're right and I will incorporate your suggestion into my code. However, so far my code never reaches this part because it fails on the `var bufferedReader` line before it ever reaches the `while` loop. Nevertheless, thanks for the improvement.